# Save option in RCP Product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Iam developing a RCP application which consists of views and editors. I can change the values and edit the values of some parameters in editor. When a value has been changed, i need to make the editor dirty as well as would also like to enable the save button. Till now, i have not implemented my save button. Could anyone guide me how to make the save button enabled as well as how can i make an editor dirty when some modifications happen in editor.

Thanks in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Girish

Comment: Kelibiano gave a more complete answer.  Basically, you have a global isDirty boolean that you set to true when you make a modification.  Once the isDirty boolean is true, the Eclipse GUI enables the save button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of the Form editor logic, hop it will help you.

```
public class TestEditor extends FormEditor {

    @Override
    protected void addPages() {
        // this method is called when the editor is being created
        // to add the necessary pages
        // page classes should be like following
        // class TestEditorPage extends FormPage
        try {
            TestEditorPage pageTest = new TestEditorPage(this);
            addPage(pageTest);
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        // this method will be called on save action
        // (or Ctrl + s shortcut)
    }

    @Override
    public void doSaveAs() {
        // this method will be called on save-as 
        //call (or Ctrl + Shift + s shortcut)
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
       // put here the call to the logic that 
       // check if the save is allowed
       return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isDirty() {
        // Here the call for the logic that 
        // defines if the editor is dirty or not
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kelibiano, Thanks for your immediate response. I have not yet implemented the save button logic. Could you please help me to achieve it? How to show a save button in toolbar. Can we use the org.eclipse.ui.file.save command for it?

Comment: First in your ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor-preWindowOpen()  method add the configurer.setShowCoolBar(true); line, then in the ApplicationActionBarAdvisor-makeActions(...) method add register(ActionFactory.SAVE.create(window)); line. and add this xml to yout plugin.xml 
    <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar id="com.example.addressbook.filetoolbar">
            <command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save" style="push" />
        </toolbar>
    </menuContribution>